# Java JFrame not resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a `JFrame`, which is the toplevel container for a window, and a single `JComponent` (that I have implemented) which is contained in the JFrame.

In part of my JComponent's logic, I need to resize the window to a specific size, but now matter what I try, it has not worked.  I have tried calling `setPreferredSize` and `setSize` on the JFrame, the JComponent, and on the `Container` returned from calling `getParent()` on the component.

I have a feeling this has something to do with not calling `pack` after changing the size, but I cannot figure out how to access the JFrame from the JComponent to call pack on it (I am no swing expert).

Thank you

Comment: `pack()` will resize for you. Don't call `pack()` if you want to manually set the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get the top level window by calling the `SwingUtilities#getWindowAncestor` method:

```
Window topLevelWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(myComponent);
topLevelWindow.pack();
```

passing in your component. Just make sure that you only call this *after the GUI has been rendered*, else you'll get a nasty NullPointerException.